# How to choose right nodes in janusgraph

Tags: java, gremlin, graph-databases, janusgraph

I need to all blue nodes or the node that the id match between different nodes in the tree, based on the maximum levels. I have this code

```
 GraphTraversal<Vertex, Map<String, List>> values = graphDbConnection.getGraphTraversalSource().V()
                .hasLabel('uuid').has('uuid', uuid).emit()
                .repeat(in().choose(values('color').is('blue'), identity(), in()))
                .times(levels)
                .map(or(has('color', 'blue'),
                        has('uuid', uuid)))
                .valueMap('uuid', 'color');
```

if between one blue node and another blue node are more than 3 or 4 incorrect nodes, the algorithm will left out the last possible one.

For example, with that code, if I ask all blues four levels above from `uuid=1` including one, it will returns 1,2,3 and will not returns 4 because between 3 and 4 are 3 black.
[image]

but for this example it will returns 1,2,3,4 because between 3 and 4 are just one or two incorrect nodes
[image]

Note: One detail here, if I remove `times(levels)` call, all blue colors will be shown no matter how many wrong colors are in between but without an stop condition, which is the key.

Comment: There are probably a few people on Earth who can code your request in gremlin in a few minutes. I would rather advise you to end you query with a .path().by(__.valueMap('uuid', 'color')) gremlin step. The returned list is easy to filter in regular java for the required result.

Comment: Thank you so much @HadoopMarc, I will try what you propose, but I already have a way to manage that case in java, I'm trying to find a best direct way with the tools provided by gremlin. Thank you!

Comment: I have found the reason, I just don't know how to fix it. The issue is in this part
`.repeat(in().choose(values('color').is('blue'), identity(), in()))` that is not sending out the blues only but few black too, so when the times reach the max levels, there are levels that are not blue and counting, then when the map arrives none blue are out but not all levels are filled with blue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when you encounter a black node, as in your second diagram, you do an `in`, but at the start of each repeat you do another `in`. So if the node after the blue one is black, it will now be also be emitted. One possible way to fix this is to change the `emit` along the lines of `emit(has('color','blue'))` so that only nodes with a blue color are kept.

Here is a simple example that hopefully shows this usage of `emit` clearly.

```
g.addV('blue').as('b1').
  addV('red').as('r1').
  addV('blue').as('b2').
  addV('red').as('r2').
  addV('blue').as('b3').
  addE('link').from('b1').to('r1').
  addE('link').from('r1').to('b2').
  addE('link').from('b2').to('r2').
  addE('link').from('r2').to('b3')
```

Using this type of a approach you can most likely simplify your query.

```java
gremlin> g.V()
==>v[42762]
==>v[42763]
==>v[42764]
==>v[42765]
==>v[42766]

gremlin> g.V(42762).emit(hasLabel('blue')).repeat(out()).times(4).label()
==>blue
==>blue
==>blue

gremlin> g.V(42762).emit().repeat(out()).times(4).label()
==>blue
==>red
==>blue
==>red
==>blue
```

Finally here is the same example with the `choose` step added.

```java
gremlin> g.V(42762).emit(hasLabel('blue')).repeat(out().choose(hasLabel('blue'),identity(),out())).times(2).label()
==>blue
==>blue
==>blue
```