# get verties and edges using gremlin

Tags: gremlin, orientdb

I'm trying to return the vertices and edges starting from a specific vertex by traversing a specific edge's label
the result i'm looking for is the vertices, edges that being traversed + all the edges of the leaf nodes

[example graph]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yQTW.png

**Expected result:**
ap1  contained p1
ap2  contained p1
p1 uses
f1  contained ap1
f2  contained f1
f3  contained f2
f3  uses
f4  contained ap2
f5  contained f4
f6  contained f5
f6  uses

**Script that generates the graph**

```
g.addV('project').property('name','p1').as('p1').addV('api').property('name','ap1').as('ap1').addV('api').property('name','ap2').as('ap2').addV('field').property('name','f1').as('f1').addV('field').property('name','f2').as('f2').addV('field').property('name','f3').as('f3').addV('field').property('name','f4').as('f4').addV('field').property('name','f5').as('f5')  addV('field').property('name','f6').as('f6').addV('table').property('name','t1').as('t1').addV('column').property('name','c1').as('c1').addV('schema').property('name','s1').as('s1').addE('contained').from('f3').to('f2').addE('contained').from('f2').to('f1').addE('contained').from('f1').to('ap1').addE('contained').from('ap1').to('p1').addE('contained').from('f6').to('f5').addE('contained').from('f5').to('f4').addE('contained').from('f4').to('ap2').addE('contained').from('ap2').to('p1').addE('uses').from('f3').to('t1').addE('uses').from('f6').to('c1').addE('uses').from('p1').to('s1')
```

Seems like i'm getting a cyclic issues (orientdb stack overflow)
while using the following query:

```java
g.V().
  has("name", "p1").
  repeat(
    bothE().
    or(hasLabel("contained"), hasLabel("uses")).
    dedup().
    bothV().
    bothE()).
    times(1).
    emit().
  path().
  unfold().
  dedup().
  aggregate('r').
  sideEffect(cap('r').unfold().hasLabel("api").aggregate('c0')).
  sideEffect(
    cap('c0').
    unfold().
    repeat(inE("contained").dedup().outV()).
      until(inE("contained").count().is(0)).
      emit().
    path().
    unfold().
    dedup().
    aggregate('c0')).
  cap('c0').
  unfold().
  aggregate('r').
  cap('r').
  unfold().
  dedup().
  limit(1000)
```

Comment: Can you please add the gremlin query with addV and addE steps that builds your sample graph?

Comment: I was about to make the same comment about a sample graph. While a picture is useful it helps people give you a tested answer if there is a sample graph provided. If you need an example of some `addV` and `addE` steps being used to create a small graph please see the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68930863/how-to-choose-right-nodes-in-janusgraph/69238423#69238423

Comment: @HadoopMarc Of course. Added

Answer (score 1):

The following query will make it
I changed the strategy to make the traversal be folded to a global list 'r'.
then concatenating the intermediate computations (c0,c1) to the list 'r'

```
g.V().
  has("name", "p1").emit().
  repeat(
    bothE().or(hasLabel("contained"), hasLabel("uses")).dedup().otherV()).
    times(1).
    as('v').
  aggregate('c0').
    by(select(all, 'v').unfold().union(identity(), bothE()).fold()).
  aggregate('c1').
    by(
      select(all, 'v').
      unfold().
      hasLabel("api").
      repeat(inE("contained").dedup().outV()).
        until(inE("contained").count().is(0)).
        emit().
      union(identity(), bothE()).
      fold()).
  fold().
  store('r').by(cap('c0')).
  store('r').by(cap('c1')).
  cap('r').
  unfold().
  unfold().
  unfold().
  dedup().
  limit(1000)
```