# Aggregation/GroupCount on graphDatabase

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, gremlin-server, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I have a graph's database in gremlin with shape like this image:

[image: Graph]

- Vertices:

  - Person
  - Event:
- Edge:

  - Attends

I need help to build a query to get results between all "Persons", with the edge as a count of all "Events" in common. The result should be something like this:

```
{
    nodes: [
      {id:"PersonA", label: "Person A"},
      {id:"PersonB", label: "Person B"},
      {id:"PersonC", label: "Person C"},
      {id:"PersonD", label: "Person D"},
      {id:"PersonE", label: "Person E"},
      {id:"PersonF", label: "Person F"},
    ],
   edges: [
      {from: "PersonA", to: "PersonB", label: 1},
      {from: "PersonA", to: "PersonC", label: 2},
      {from: "PersonA", to: "PersonD", label: 2},
      {from: "PersonA", to: "PersonE", label: 1},
      {from: "PersonA", to: "PersonF", label: 1},
      {from: "PersonB", to: "PersonC", label: 1},
      {from: "PersonB", to: "PersonD", label: 1},
      {from: "PersonC", to: "PersonD", label: 2},
      {from: "PersonC", to: "PersonE", label: 1},
      {from: "PersonC", to: "PersonF", label: 1},
      {from: "PersonD", to: "PersonE", label: 1},
      {from: "PersonD", to: "PersonF", label: 1},
      {from: "PersonE", to: "PersonF", label: 1}
   ]
}
```

I'm struggling on this for a few hours and can't something close for what I'm looking for.

Comment: It will help people provide tested answers if you can add to your question some `addV` and `addE` steps that build the sample graph. The answer to this question shows such a small sample graph being created: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68930863/how-to-choose-right-nodes-in-janusgraph/69238423#69238423

Comment: i already did it myself this time and have an answer coming

Comment: And Thanks @stephen, I'm waiting for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

A picture is nice, but when asking questions about Gremlin it's best to provide a Gremlin script to create your data:

```
g.addV('person').property(id,'a').as('a').         
  addV('person').property(id,'b').as('b').
  addV('person').property(id,'c').as('c').
  addV('person').property(id,'d').as('d').  
  addV('person').property(id,'e').as('e').
  addV('person').property(id,'f').as('f').  
  addV('event').property(id,'1').as('1').   
  addV('event').property(id,'2').as('2').  
  addE('attends').from('a').to('1').
  addE('attends').from('a').to('2').
  addE('attends').from('b').to('2').
  addE('attends').from('c').to('1').
  addE('attends').from('c').to('2').
  addE('attends').from('d').to('1').
  addE('attends').from('d').to('2').
  addE('attends').from('e').to('1').
  addE('attends').from('f').to('1').iterate()
```

I went with this approach to solve your problem:

```
g.V().hasLabel('person').as('s').
  out().in().
  where(neq('s')).
  path().by(id).
  groupCount().
    by(union(limit(local,1),tail(local,1)).fold()).
  unfold().
  dedup().
    by(select(keys).order(local)).
  order().
    by(select(keys).limit(local,1)).
    by(select(keys).tail(local,1))
```

which produces the output your seeking:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').as('s').
......1>   out().in().
......2>   where(neq('s')).
......3>   path().by(id).
......4>   groupCount().
......5>     by(union(limit(local,1),tail(local,1)).fold()).
......6>   unfold().
......7>   dedup().
......8>     by(select(keys).order(local)).
......9>   order().by(select(keys).limit(local,1))
==>[a, b]=1
==>[a, e]=1
==>[a, c]=2
==>[a, d]=2
==>[a, f]=1
==>[b, c]=1
==>[b, d]=1
==>[c, d]=2
==>[c, e]=1
==>[c, f]=1
==>[d, e]=1
==>[d, f]=1
==>[e, f]=1
```

The approach above utilizes `path()` to gather the "person->event<-person" that Gremlin travels over and avoid retracing steps with `where(neq('s'))`. It then does a `groupCount()` by the "person" vertices which represent the person pairs. We now have a `Map` with the person pairs and their counts as you want but it needs a bit of post-processing so we `unfold()` the `Map` to key-value pairs. The first step is to `dedup()` by the person pairs as the `Map` currently contains things like "a->b" and "b->a" and we don't need both, so deduping by the ordered list of those pairs, will give us the unique list. Finally, we add some `order()` to make the results look exactly like yours.

I suppose you could try to `dedup()` immediately after the `path()` and avoid some extra work in `groupCount()`.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen. This is exactly what i looking for. And your explanation is perfect for me. Now I'm getting understand a bit more about graph's database :)