# Count edges by vertex in Gremlin

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

Brand new to Gremlin.  Have a graph like this Vertices = People, Items; Edges = Likes, Purchases.

I'm trying to count the number of purchases everyone has made with output as:

Greg, 4

Naomi, 0

Kyunghee, 2

Thank you,

Comment: It helps to provide tested answers if you can provide the `addV` and `addE` steps that build a sample graph. The answer to this post has such an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68930863/how-to-choose-right-nodes-in-janusgraph/69238423#69238423

Comment: I went ahead and added an answer given you are new to Gremlin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this simple graph

```java
 g.addV('Person').property('name','Greg').as('g').
   addV('Person').property('name','Naomi').as('n').
   addV('Person').property('name','Kyunghee').as('k').
   addV('Item').property('name','book').as('book').
   addV('Item').property('name','TV').as('tv').
   addV('Item').property('name','laptop').as('laptop').
   addV('Item').property('name','car').as('car').
   addE('Purchased').from('g').to('book').
   addE('Purchased').from('g').to('tv').
   addE('Purchased').from('g').to('laptop').
   addE('Purchased').from('g').to('car').
   addE('Purchased').from('k').to('book').
   addE('Purchased').from('k').to('tv')
```

One way to calculate the purchases is to just group the people using their name and their purchases.

```java
gremlin>  g.V().hasLabel('Person').
......1>    group().
......2>      by('name').
......3>      by(out('Purchased').count())

==>[Naomi:0,Kyunghee:2,Greg:4]
```