# Gremlin get highest value from list of edges related to a single vertice

Tags: javascript, gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop

I am a beginner in gremlin with Tinkerpop. I've this graph:

```js
// -------- VERTICES ------------
// USERS:

 :> g.addV("user").property("name", "test1").property("location", "karachi")

 :> g.addV("user").property("name", "test2").property("location", "lahore")

 :> g.addV("user").property("name", "test3").property("location", "islamabad")

 :> g.addV("user").property("name", "test4").property("location", "karachi")


// RESTAURANTS:

 :> g.addV("restaurant").property("name", "restaurant1").property("location", "karachi")


 :> g.addV("restaurant").property("name", "restaurant2").property("location", "lahore")

 :> g.addV("restaurant").property("name", "restaurant3").property("location", "islamabad")

 :> g.addV("restaurant").property("name", "restaurant4").property("location", "faisalabad")


// CUISINES:

 :> g.addV("cuisine").property("name", "cuisine1")

 :> g.addV("cuisine").property("name", "cuisine2")

 :> g.addV("cuisine").property("name", "cuisine3")

 :> g.addV("cuisine").property("name", "cuisine4")

 :> g.addV("cuisine").property("name", "cuisine5")


// -------- EDGES ------------

FRIENDS:

 :> g.addE("friend").from(__.V(0)).to(__.V(6)).property("became_friends_at", new Date())

 :> g.addE("friend").from(__.V(6)).to(__.V(0)).property("became_friends_at", new Date())

 :> g.addE("friend").from(__.V(6)).to(__.V(9)).property("became_friends_at", new Date())

 :> g.addE("friend").from(__.V(9)).to(__.V(6)).property("became_friends_at", new Date())

 :> g.addE("friend").from(__.V(6)).to(__.V(3)).property("became_friends_at", new Date())

 :> g.addE("friend").from(__.V(3)).to(__.V(6)).property("became_friends_at", new Date())


// REVIEWS:

 :> g.addE("review").from(__.V(3)).to(__.V(12)).property("value", 3.7).property("rated_at", new Date()).property("upvotes", 8).property("downvotes", 4)

 :> g.addE("review").from(__.V(0)).to(__.V(12)).property("value", 4).property("rated_at", new Date()).property("upvotes", 8).property("downvotes", 4)

 :> g.addE("review").from(__.V(0)).to(__.V(21)).property("value", 2.5).property("rated_at", new Date()).property("upvotes", 8).property("downvotes", 4)

 :> g.addE("review").from(__.V(6)).to(__.V(15)).property("value", 3.9).property("rated_at", new Date()).property("upvotes", 8).property("downvotes", 4)

 :> g.addE("review").from(__.V(9)).to(__.V(18)).property("value", 5).property("rated_at", new Date()).property("upvotes", 8).property("downvotes", 4)



// SERVED CUISINES:

 :> g.addE("serves").from(__.V(18)).to(__.V(24))

 :> g.addE("serves").from(__.V(18)).to(__.V(26))

 :> g.addE("serves").from(__.V(18)).to(__.V(32))

 :> g.addE("serves").from(__.V(15)).to(__.V(32))

 :> g.addE("serves").from(__.V(15)).to(__.V(24))

 :> g.addE("serves").from(__.V(21)).to(__.V(30))

 :> g.addE("serves").from(__.V(12)).to(__.V(28))

 :> g.addE("serves").from(__.V(12)).to(__.V(26))

 :> g.addE("serves").from(__.V(12)).to(__.V(30))



 :> g.addV("restaurant").property("name", "restaurant5").property("location", "karachi")

 :> g.addV("restaurant").property("name", "restaurant6").property("location", "karachi")

 :> g.addV("restaurant").property("name", "restaurant7").property("location", "karachi")

 :> g.addE("serves").to(__.V(26)).from(__.V(54))

 :> g.addE("serves").to(__.V(26)).from(__.V(60))



 :> g.addE("review").from(__.V(6)).to(__.V(54)).property("rated_at", new Date()).property("downvotes", 1).property("value",4).property("upvotes",4)
 :> g.addE("review").from(__.V(0)).to(__.V(54)).property("rated_at", new Date()).property("downvotes", 3).property("value",2).property("upvotes",4.7)
 :> g.addE("review").from(__.V(9)).to(__.V(54)).property("rated_at", new Date()).property("downvotes", 1).property("value",12).property("upvotes",3)
 :> g.addE("review").from(__.V(3)).to(__.V(54)).property("rated_at", new Date()).property("downvotes", 9).property("value",3).property("upvotes",2)

 :> g.addE("review").from(__.V(6)).to(__.V(60)).property("rated_at", new Date()).property("downvotes", 3).property("value",5).property("upvotes",4)
 :> g.addE("review").from(__.V(0)).to(__.V(60)).property("rated_at", new Date()).property("downvotes", 2).property("value",3).property("upvotes",5)
 :> g.addE("review").from(__.V(9)).to(__.V(60)).property("rated_at", new Date()).property("downvotes", 5).property("value",5).property("upvotes",1)
 :> g.addE("review").from(__.V(3)).to(__.V(60)).property("rated_at", new Date()).property("downvotes", 1).property("value",2).property("upvotes",5)
```

I want to create a query that takes the userId `g.V(id)`, and get all of its friends `outE("friend").inV()`, and their only highest review edge `outE("review").order().by("value", desc)`

I've created this function (JS):

```
async function init() {
  const query = g
    .V()
    .hasId(6)
    .outE("friend")
    .inV()
    .hasLabel("user")
    .outE("review")
    .order()
    .by("value", queryOrder);

  const dataRaw = await query.toList();
  await dc.close();
  const data = JSON.stringify(normalizeData(dataRaw as any), null, 1);
  console.log(data);
}
```

But this returns all the reviews of a single friend. I want only the highest review of them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I will try to take a look at this and thanks for providing the sample graph. That is always helpful when testing answers. However, please note that you should not assume what the vertex IDs will be when adding edges as that will greatly vary between databases and even using the same database.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! This query is specific to the Tinkerpop server session. I don't know how to save the data. I've created this text file to re initialize the graph when I start the server.

Comment: You can save the data using the `g.io()` steps. In general, when creating a graph using `addV` steps like this it's better to use `as` labels. Here is an example of where that is being done https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69959434/count-edges-by-vertex-in-gremlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using TinkerGraph, I setup your data as follows,

```java
conf = new BaseConfiguration()
conf.setProperty("gremlin.tinkergraph.vertexIdManager","LONG")
conf.setProperty("gremlin.tinkergraph.edgeIdManager","LONG")
conf.setProperty("gremlin.tinkergraph.vertexPropertyIdManager","LONG")
graph = TinkerGraph.open(conf)
g=graph.traversal()

g.addV("user").property("name", "test1").property("location", "karachi").
   addV("user").property("name", "test2").property("location", "lahore").
   addV("user").property("name", "test3").property("location", "islamabad").
   addV("user").property("name", "test4").property("location", "karachi").
   addV("restaurant").property("name", "restaurant1").property("location", "karachi").
   addV("restaurant").property("name", "restaurant2").property("location", "lahore").
   addV("restaurant").property("name", "restaurant3").property("location", "islamabad").
   addV("restaurant").property("name", "restaurant4").property("location", "faisalabad").
   addV("cuisine").property("name", "cuisine1").
   addV("cuisine").property("name", "cuisine2").
   addV("cuisine").property("name", "cuisine3").
   addV("cuisine").property("name", "cuisine4").
   addV("cuisine").property("name", "cuisine5").
   addE("friend").from(__.V(0)).to(__.V(6)).property("became_friends_at", new Date()).
   addE("friend").from(__.V(6)).to(__.V(0)).property("became_friends_at", new Date()).
   addE("friend").from(__.V(6)).to(__.V(9)).property("became_friends_at", new Date()).
   addE("friend").from(__.V(9)).to(__.V(6)).property("became_friends_at", new Date()).
   addE("friend").from(__.V(6)).to(__.V(3)).property("became_friends_at", new Date()).
   addE("friend").from(__.V(3)).to(__.V(6)).property("became_friends_at", new Date()).
   addE("review").from(__.V(3)).to(__.V(12)).property("value", 3.7).property("rated_at", new Date()).property("upvotes", 8).property("downvotes", 4).
   addE("review").from(__.V(0)).to(__.V(12)).property("value", 4).property("rated_at", new Date()).property("upvotes", 8).property("downvotes", 4).
   addE("review").from(__.V(0)).to(__.V(21)).property("value", 2.5).property("rated_at", new Date()).property("upvotes", 8).property("downvotes", 4).
   addE("review").from(__.V(6)).to(__.V(15)).property("value", 3.9).property("rated_at", new Date()).property("upvotes", 8).property("downvotes", 4).
   addE("review").from(__.V(9)).to(__.V(18)).property("value", 5).property("rated_at", new Date()).property("upvotes", 8).property("downvotes", 4).
   addE("serves").from(__.V(18)).to(__.V(24)).
   addE("serves").from(__.V(18)).to(__.V(26)).
   addE("serves").from(__.V(18)).to(__.V(32)).
   addE("serves").from(__.V(15)).to(__.V(32)).
   addE("serves").from(__.V(15)).to(__.V(24)).
   addE("serves").from(__.V(21)).to(__.V(30)).
   addE("serves").from(__.V(12)).to(__.V(28)).
   addE("serves").from(__.V(12)).to(__.V(26)).
   addE("serves").from(__.V(12)).to(__.V(30)).
   addV("restaurant").property("name", "restaurant5").property("location", "karachi").
   addV("restaurant").property("name", "restaurant6").property("location", "karachi").
   addV("restaurant").property("name", "restaurant7").property("location", "karachi").
   addE("serves").to(__.V(26)).from(__.V(54)).
   addE("serves").to(__.V(26)).from(__.V(60)).
   addE("review").from(__.V(6)).to(__.V(54)).property("rated_at", new Date()).property("downvotes", 1).property("value",4).property("upvotes",4).
   addE("review").from(__.V(0)).to(__.V(54)).property("rated_at", new Date()).property("downvotes", 3).property("value",2).property("upvotes",4.7).
   addE("review").from(__.V(9)).to(__.V(54)).property("rated_at", new Date()).property("downvotes", 1).property("value",12).property("upvotes",3).
   addE("review").from(__.V(3)).to(__.V(54)).property("rated_at", new Date()).property("downvotes", 9).property("value",3).property("upvotes",2).
   addE("review").from(__.V(6)).to(__.V(60)).property("rated_at", new Date()).property("downvotes", 3).property("value",5).property("upvotes",4).
   addE("review").from(__.V(0)).to(__.V(60)).property("rated_at", new Date()).property("downvotes", 2).property("value",3).property("upvotes",5).
   addE("review").from(__.V(9)).to(__.V(60)).property("rated_at", new Date()).property("downvotes", 5).property("value",5).property("upvotes",1).
   addE("review").from(__.V(3)).to(__.V(60)).property("rated_at", new Date()).property("downvotes", 1).property("value",2).property("upvotes",5)
```

I then slightly modified your query to only return 1 edge per friend using `local` scope, having sorted by descending value. I was not sure from the question if you just wanted the edge back or the whole path. If you need the path please add a comment and I will update the answer.

```java
gremlin> g.V(6).
......1>   outE("friend").
......2>   inV().
......3>   hasLabel("user").
......4>   local(
......5>     outE("review").
......6>     order().
......7>       by("value", desc).
......8>     limit(1)) 
==>e[41][0-review->12]
==>e[67][9-review->54]
==>e[40][3-review->12]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I see you're one of the main contributors in gremlin-related queries and I appreciate that. For some reason, this is returning `value: 4` above `value:12`:


```js
gremlin> :> g.V(6).outE("friend").inV().hasLabel("user").local(__.outE("review").order().by("value", desc).limit(1).valueMap()) 
==>{upvotes=8, rated_at=Wed Nov 17 17:11:58 PKT 2021, downvotes=4, value=4}
==>{upvotes=3, rated_at=Wed Nov 17 17:11:58 PKT 2021, downvotes=1, value=12}
==>{upvotes=8, rated_at=Wed Nov 17 17:11:58 PKT 2021, downvotes=4, value=3.7}
```

Comment: Nvm, just had to use order().bY() at the end. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Also, if you can explain or link to a resource on what is `local()` exactly, that will be helpful to me. The definition in Tinkerpop doc is way hard to understand.

Comment: Have you seen http://www.kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html ?

Comment: and related links http://www.kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.pdf and https://github.com/krlawrence/graph. Specific to local look here http://www.kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html#local